# when opacity:0 or visibility:hidden, class is not applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a hidden class in CSS.

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

and when the button is clicked, I call this function:

```
const openModal = () => {
  modal.classList.remove('hidden');
  overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  

  for (let i = 0; i < modalItems.length; i++) {
    if (
      modalItems[i].innerText === document.querySelector('#default').innerText
    ) {
      modalItems[i].classList.add('item-background');
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is, if I use `display:none`, the transition is not applied. So, I replace `display:none` with `opacity:0` / `visibility:hidden`. After that, the animation is applied but the problem is that `item-background` class is not applied, when modal is opened.

Comment: I think you are messing up  CSS specificity rules here

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a logical reason why altering the css would make your string compare conditional not work. The reason is more likely to be slight differences in the 2 strings. Comparing innerText of 2 different elements can be problematic, try normalizing them as much as you can using `toLowerCase()` (if you don't need case sensitivity) and `trim()`, like:

```
let equals = modalItems[i].innerText.toLowerCase().trim() === document.querySelector('#default').innerText.toLowerCase().trim();
if (equals) {
  //
}
```